# MRAID tag Errors

Tags: mraid

I'm working with a MRAID third party tag provider, we've been reported that a few MRAID tags are not serving properly. On checking with their reports we've found a few reasons, among them; "mraid object doesn't exist" has contributed a lot of rejected impressions. Could anyone of you help me understand what exactly the error "*mraid object doesn't exist*" mean?

Thank you All.

Answer (score 0):

Mraid tags will work inside Mraid Compatible Web View Containers. In case the webview (inside IOS/ANDROID/Windows APPS) doesn't support mraid (which is usually provided by the Ad SDK vendor to the APPS creators), you will not have reference to the mraid available as a result your Ad may not work at all inside APPs.

However in case you are serving Mraid tags only in mobile web applications then browser won't provide you the reference to mraid object so in that case mraid object will always be undefined. So in mobile web applications ad creators must not use mraid at all only it shall be used wheen the mraid object exists.e.g

```
if (typeof mraid == 'undefined'){
        //MOst probably mobile web
        //Or If you are sure that your ad is presented in APPs, most probably then 
        //their Mobile Ad SDK's don't support mraid
}else {
      if (mraid.getState() == 'loading')
      {
          mraid.addEventListener("ready", mraidIsReady); //wait until marid is loaded and ready
      }else{
            //Add is ready and you can call display ad related function here
      }

}
```